# Port netcat request info to bash script

Tags: webserver, tcp, netcat

I have this super simple TCP server that takes requests and returns the output of `handler.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true ; do nc -l -p 1234 -e handler.sh; done
```

I'd like to port the requested path to `handler.sh` as a parameter, so that if `0.0.0.0:1234/foo/bar` was hit, `handler.sh` would know.

Is this possible?

Thanks :)

Comment: Requested path? What do you mean? Some protocol like HTTP that has paths?

Comment: @phk Yes I should have specified I'm working primarily with HTTP. Ideally if an HTTP GET is sent to 0.0.0.0:1234/foo/bar, handler.sh is executed with parameter "foo/bar" or "/foo/bar"

Comment: Well, parsing HTTP isn't that trivial (esp. if you want to do it robust and correctly), a quick internet search revealed that there are indeed HTTP servers written in `bash`, like https://github.com/avleen/bashttpd probably too much for you though.